# log4j hide the name of the jar file

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

According to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

[image]

Is there a way to avoid that particular behavior? I don't want to show the JAR.

I believe that some replacement can be done using %replace, BUT, I need this to work with both log4j and log4j2 (.properties, .xml).

Right now my pattern is:

```
pattern="%5p {%d} [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n"
```

Comment: Please don’t use images to show text.  Copy the text into your question, and precede it with `>` so it appears as a quoted block.  Regular text is a lot easier to read than that image, and as a bonus, search engines can see the text, so other people with your problem will be more likely to find your question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use the wrong default pattern (if not present will be %xEx used). Silly me. Use %ex.